# Удалить кавычки в json_array MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

У меня есть запрос, выглядит он примерно так

```
SELECT id,JSON_ARRAY(classname, color, inventory, tuning_data) 
FROM vehicles 
WHERE id = 8
```

ответ получаю такой

```
8,["kraz", "blue", "[]", "[]"]
```

Проблема в том, что последние два значения я получаю в кавычках, а нужно без, пропарсить отдельно в коде нельзя, нужно только используя SQL, я пробовал подставить туда JSON_UNQUOTE, но это не увенчалось успехом. База данных MariaDB.

Comment: Выложите пример исходных данных в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скриптов. И укажите **точную** версию сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте тип `JSON` для полей `inventory`, `tuning_data`:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles (
    id int, classname varchar(32), color varchar(32), inventory json, tuning_data json 
);

INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES (8, "kraz", "blue", "[]", "[]");

SELECT id, JSON_ARRAY(classname, color, inventory, tuning_data) 
FROM vehicles 
WHERE id = 8;
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=9e650d1b74e4ba65204a0f39d89bd82b&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)